# How to do exponentiation in Bash

Tags: bash, syntax, operators

I tried

```
echo 10**2
```

which prints `10**2`. How to calculate the right result, 100?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the [`let` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-let):

```
let var=10**2   # sets var to 100.
echo $var       # prints 100
```

or [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html):

```
var=$((10**2))  # sets var to 100.
```

Arithmetic expansion has the advantage of allowing you to do [shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html) and then just use the expression without storing it in a variable:

```
echo $((10**2)) # prints 100.
```

For large numbers you might want to use the [exponentiation operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_node/bc_10.html) of the [external command `bc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/) as:

```
bash:$ echo 2^100 | bc
1267650600228229401496703205376
```

If you want to store the above result in a variable you can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) either via the `$()` syntax:

```
var=$(echo 2^100 | bc)
```

or the older backtick syntax:

```
var=`echo 2^100 | bc`
```

Note that command substitution is not the same as arithmetic expansion:

```
$(( )) # arithmetic expansion
$( )   # command substitution
```

Comment: Instead of `$(( ... ))` it's also possible to use `$[ ... ]`. I find the later visually more appealing but that's just my taste. Don't know if there are any differences between the two, though. It seems they behave the same.

Comment: Alberto: all this parenthesis, lets and $ are needed because bash, being a simple command-line interpreter, does better assuming everything is a string and should be treated as such, unless explicitly indicated otherwise. Saludos!

Comment: @DarkDust `$[...]` is an older deprecated syntax. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209833/what-does-a-dollar-sign-followed-by-a-square-bracket-mean-in-bash

Comment: **NOTE:** `$(( ... ))` does not work. Instead, `$( ... )` has to be used. See @firefly's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130651/8387076) below.

Comment: @WrichikBasu I submitted an edit; it's fixed now.

Answer (score 7):

Various ways:

### [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html)

```
echo $((10**2))
```

### [Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html)

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 10^2}'  # POSIX standard
awk 'BEGIN{print 10**2}' # GNU awk extension
```

### [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_node/bc_10.html)

```
echo '10 ^ 2' | bc
```

### [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_chapter/dc_4.html)

```
dc -e '10 2 ^ p'
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually `var=$((echo 2^100 | bc))` doesn't work - bash is trying to do math inside `(())`. But a
command line sequence is there instead so it creates an error

`var=$(echo 2^100 | bc)` works as the value is the result of the command line executing inside
`()`

Comment: This is very helpful You should put it as a comment to the answer above.

Comment: Good catch, by the way; the other, accepted commands followed the `$((...))` pattern ([Double Parentheses Construct](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html), source Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide, "permits arithmetic expansion and evaluation"). Here, as you've noted, we need Command Substitution, i.e. the `$(...)` construct. The ABS guide [notes](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), "The `$(...)` has superceded backticks". The Bash Beginners Guide, [section 3.4.5-6](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html), has both described right next to each other.